# Series plot will not display properly (Fourier Series)

Tags: plotting, warning-messages, series-expansion

```
c1[n_] := 1/2/Pi Integrate[Sign[x] Exp[-I n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}]; 
c2[n_] = Simplify[c1[n], Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]]; 
c[n_] := If[n == 0, c1[0] = 0];
f5[x_] = Sum[c[k] Exp[I k x], {k, -10, 10}]; 
Plot[{f5[x], Sign[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

I am trying to plot the $Sign[x]$ function and the series:  $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty \dfrac{i(-1)^n - i}{n\pi}e^{inx} $ (which should be the answer to the integral in the code) on the same graph, but I cannot seem to get it to work. It displays no error, just an empty graph.

Comment: The expression `If[n == 0, c1[0] = 0];` does not make sense to me and it is the reason that `f5[x]` contains unwanted `Null` signs.

Comment: I remove it and get the division by 0 error. I try and use a different method to avoid the division by 0 error and displays an empty graph or just the Sign[x] graph.

Answer (score 3):

You only have to make sure that the coefficient `c[n]` in the Fourier series is defined for all `n`. This means that the `If` statement defining `c[n]` must return a value *not only* for `n==0` as it does in your attempt, but also for other values of `n`. So all you have to do is change your code to

```
c1[n_] := 1/2/Pi Integrate[Sign[x] Exp[-I n x], {x, -Pi, Pi}];
c2[n_] = Simplify[c1[n], Assumptions -> Element[n, Integers]];
c[n_] := If[n == 0, c1[0] = 0, c2[n]];
f5[x_] = Sum[c[k] Exp[I k x], {k, -10, 10}];
Plot[{f5[x], Sign[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}]
```

and the plot comes out as expected:

[image: sign Fourier]

The way you use the `If` statement suggests that there may be another misunderstanding. What you need is for `If` to return two alternative results, not to execute the assignment `c1[0] = 0` as you do it. That's simply unnecessary. So you may as well simplify it to

```
c[n_] := If[n == 0, 0, c2[n]];
```

Also, you could use

```
c2[n_] = FourierCoefficient[Sign[x], x, n]
```

instead of the explicit integration.

Comment: You haven't been here for a few months. Welcome back +1!

Comment: Thanks @Artes - I hope I didn't miss too much, I almost didn't check in at all during the fall...

Answer (score 2):

All the even terms vanish and using definition c2:

```
fun[x_, r_?OddQ] := 
  Sum[c2[k] Exp[I k x], {k, Join[Range[-r, -1, 2], Range[1, r, 2]]}];
fun[x_, r_] := fun[x, r - 1]
```

Animating using:

```
Table[Plot[{fun[x, j], Sign[x]}, {x, -Pi, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Thick, Red}}], {j, 1, 21, 2}]
```

[image]