# How can I plot an exponential Fourier series?

Tags: plotting, complex, fourier-analysis

Iam triying to plot summatory of the next function:

```
(e^(i*n*t*wo)*Sin[n*Pi/2])/(n*pi)
```

I have no problem plotting a trigonometric fourier serie, so the only problem is plotting the complex i. I have watched several videos where they use an uppercase I instead of an lowercase i, I have already tried that but with no results. The functions that I use are:

```
s[i_,t_] := 1/2 + Sum[(e^(i*n*t*wo)*Sin[n*Pi/2])/(n*pi),{n,-i,-1}] + Sum[(e^(i*n*t*wo)*Sin[n*Pi/2])/(n*pi),{n,1,i}] 

Plot[s[10],{t,-10,10}]
```

First I made a declaration of a function where the summatories are declared, the i in the Plot[] function is the number of iterations.

I offer an apologize my english is not the best one and I dont know how to make the ecuation look pretty. Anyway thanks a lot.

Comment: You will want to use `Re[]` or `Im[]` to see the individual parts in `Plot[]`, or use `ReIm[]` in conjunction with `ParametricPlot[]`. Also, the exponential constant is `E` (capitalization matters!) and the exponential function is `Exp[]`.

Comment: First you should look at the *Mathematica* documentation for `Exp`, then also search for examples here. See [this Q&A](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/39872/245) or [this one](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2537/245), for instance. Your definition is incorrect because `s` uses two arguments but you in `Plot` you're calling it with just one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be what you are after:

```
s[i_, t_] := 1/2 + Sum[(E^(I*n*t*wo)*Sin[n*Pi/2])/(n*Pi), {n, -i, -1}] + 
                   Sum[(E^(I*n*t*wo)*Sin[n*Pi/2])/(n*Pi), {n, 1, i}];
wo = 1; 
Plot[s[5, t], {t, -10, 10}]
```

[image]

Comment: yeeei!!! Thanks, but could you please explain me why you use the I and the E?

Comment: Because as I said, **capitalization matters**, @Mac. Those are the symbols used by *Mathematica* for the constants you know.

Comment: Consider the difference between `?E` and `?e`.